# Directly Uploading to YouTube via PHP on YouTube's Data API v3

Tags: php, zend-framework, youtube, youtube-api, gdata

From everything I have gathered, this seems to be relatively hard to accomplish on any existing library today. My first attempt to upload a video directly from a server to YouTube was with Zend Framework 1. ZF1 worked great but once updating to ZF2 and installing the ZendGData package everything went to shit.

Apparantly, ZendGData is no longer maintained and is fundamentally broken as it has calls to non-existent methods in Zend's HTTP package. ([Unresolved GitHub issue](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendGData/issues/6)).

So now I'm looking for an alternative. I found [google-api-php-client](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/) which appears to be the standard for YouTube Data API v3 but I see very limited documentation and have only found examples of how to upload via browser and not from the server.

Here is my ZF2 code snippet:

```
$entry = new ZendGData\YouTube\VideoEntry();
$src = $this->youtube->newMediaFileSource($loc);
$src->setContentType('video/quicktime');
$src->setSlug($loc);
$entry->setMediaSource($src);
$entry->setVideoTitle($title);
$entry->setVideoDescription($desc);
$entry->setVideoCategory('Games');
$entry->setVideoPrivate();

try {
    $entry = $this->youtube->insertEntry($entry, self::$UPLOAD_URL, 'ZendGData\YouTube\VideoEntry');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $m = $e->getMessage();
    return array("err" => "Error: $m");
}
```

Everything goes as planned up until `insertEntry` where the previously mentioned issue arises with `setRawData` being called in Zend's Http Client implementation.

So essentially:

- What is the next-gen method of uploading videos directly to YouTube?
- If there is no easy way, is there a workaround for my ZF2 code?